# Looking for this particular reference

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, specific-reference

I am studying [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.27.1466) paper: *Gravitational radiation from a particle infalling radially into a Schwarzschild black hole* by Davis et al.

It deals with the calculation of the energy spectrum of the gravitational waves emitted by a point particle falling radially into the black hole. It says that two methods were used for the calculation of the energy spectrum: a direct integration of the Regge-Wheeler equation and a method devised by Zerilli based on Green's function. The authors write that details about the first method *will be published elsewhere*.

I cannot find this *elsewhere*: can anyone help me finding this reference? (If it has been published at all)

Comment: Could this be it: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.5.2932 ?

Comment: @A.V.S. No it seems they use the second method in this paper

Comment: How about this one: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.7.972 ?

Comment: @A.V.S. No still using second method